# Generate report using api function not working in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on generate report function. While hitting page url it getting data from api using curl request.With in embedded code i have used one function getProfileMarketplace function returning no response and it results unable to  generate report. While in User Bundle  profile_marketplace function is defined and in top it is defined private. In User repository function is used to get active ppc user.

controller code

```
public function ppcReports()
    {
        /** @var CurlRequest $curlRequest */
        $curlRequest = $this->get('app.advertise.request');
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $users = $entityManager->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->getActivePPCUsers();
       foreach($users as $user) 
       {

         $refresh_token = $user->getRefreshToken();
        $marketplace = $user->getProfileMarketplace();
           //var_dump($marketplace);
         $regionResponse = $curlRequest->regionBymarketplace($marketplace) ;
         $region = json_decode($regionResponse->getContent());

        $AdvertiseProfile = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:AdvertiseProfile')->getUserProfile($user->getId());

          if(!empty($AdvertiseProfile))
          {
              $profiles =  $AdvertiseProfile[0]->getProfileDetails();
             $requestParameter = array("userId"=>$user->getId(),
                                      "refreshToken" => $refresh_token,
                                      "region" => $region->region,
                                      "sandbox" => $region->sandbox,
                                      "profiles" => $profiles
                                    ) ;

          $req_date = date('Ymd',strtotime("-1 days"));
          $reportTypes = array('campaigns','adGroups','keywords','productAds') ;

              foreach($reportTypes as $reportType)
              {
                  switch ($reportType) {
                    case "campaigns":
                        $reportData = array(
                              "requestType" => "campaigns",
                               "campaignType" => "sponsoredProducts",
                               "reportDate" => $req_date ,
                               "metrics" => "impressions,clicks,cost,avgImpressionPosition,attributedConversions1dSameSKU,attributedSales1dSameSKU,attributedConversions14dSameSKU,attributedSales14dSameSKU,attributedConversions7dSameSKU,attributedSales7dSameSKU,attributedConversions30dSameSKU,attributedSales30dSameSKU"
                              ) ; 


                        break;
                    case "adGroups":
                       $reportData = array(
                              "requestType" => "adGroups",
                               "campaignType" => "sponsoredProducts",
                               "reportDate" => $req_date ,
                               "metrics" => "impressions,clicks,cost,avgImpressionPosition,attributedConversions1dSameSKU,attributedSales1dSameSKU,attributedConversions14dSameSKU,attributedSales14dSameSKU,attributedConversions7dSameSKU,attributedSales7dSameSKU,attributedConversions30dSameSKU,attributedSales30dSameSKU"
                              ) ; 


                        break;
                    case "keywords":
                        $reportData = array(
                             "requestType" => "keywords",
                             "campaignType" => "sponsoredProducts",
                               "reportDate" => $req_date ,
                               "segment" => "query",
                               "metrics" => "impressions,clicks,cost,avgImpressionPosition,attributedConversions1dSameSKU,attributedSales1dSameSKU,attributedConversions14dSameSKU,attributedSales14dSameSKU,attributedConversions7dSameSKU,attributedSales7dSameSKU,attributedConversions30dSameSKU,attributedSales30dSameSKU"
                              ) ; 

                        break;
                    case "productAds":
                        $reportData = array(
                             "requestType" => "productAds",
                             "campaignType" => "sponsoredProducts",
                               "reportDate" => $req_date ,
                               "metrics" => "impressions,clicks,cost,avgImpressionPosition,attributedConversions1dSameSKU,attributedSales1dSameSKU,attributedConversions14dSameSKU,attributedSales14dSameSKU,attributedConversions7dSameSKU,attributedSales7dSameSKU,attributedConversions30dSameSKU,attributedSales30dSameSKU,sku,asin,currency,campaignId,adGroupId,campaignName,adGroupName"
                              ) ; 


                   }

                $Reportresponse = $curlRequest->genratereport($requestParameter,$reportData);
              }


            }           


        } 
        die('done for all reports');
    }
```

app bundle code:

```
public function getProfileMarketplace()
    {
        return $this->profile_marketplace;

    }
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: its not generating report

Comment: @PriyaNegi Please post the code of $curlRequest (service).

Exactly methods generateReport and regionBymarketplace.

With following code it's very hard to help you. You must do some dump's / die's yourself. Debugging skill will help you later.

Comment: i have check it using var_dump and die and with in marketplace variable iam not getting any data .